# In ArcMap, how to create random points of a specific amount in each polygon?

Tags: arcmap, vector, random

I am doing an accuracy assessment of land-use product and need random points as test points. What I'm trying to do is to generate different numbers of random points in different polygons (like 5 for smaller ones and 10 for bigger ones). But in ArcMap, the tool to do this can only generate a specific total amount of points, or to create points according to a specific field for the constrained feature class.

I tried to create a field called 'RP amount' and use field calculator to do some math about the amount of random point using area data, but there are many polygons belong to one parcel, and it is difficult for those polygons to have an evenly distributed random points.

Comment: What do the polygons look like (Irregular boundaries, hexagons, circles, etc.)? Could you use area or perimeter to make the decision to add n points? " Do you use Python?

Comment: One approach would be to create random points across your entire feature class (so some inside and outside your polygons) and then delete the ones you don't want.

Comment: Indeed, @Paul is correct. Use the area of the polygon to determine density, weight that by ratio of polygon area to envelope area, then cushion that by a constant. If too many are within the polygon, grab just the first N points; if too few, increase the target count and repeat.